# Are there ways to add lines in the axes of a matplotlib figure

Tags: matplotlib

I am looking through the documentation of matplotlib for the purpose of adding a tick that separate the axes

http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html

I've already have label that associate with a list of ticks

```
axes._setXTicks(ticks, labels, **kwargs)
```

so I want a thicker line for the additional tick, something like this would be great

```
axes._setXTicks([0, 5, 7, 10, 15], ["0","5", "thicker tick", "10", "15], **kwargs)
```

although I want the thicker tick line to be actually a tick that is wider but without labels

Is this possible.

I've tried looking through the document but the closest thing I found is

```
axes.axvline(7, *args, **kwargs)
```

which adds a line through the entire graph in the xth position (7 in this case), although I only wanted a thicker tick

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. Just use the additional arguments `ymin` and `ymax` of `axvline` to set the tick length:

```
ymin, ymax = axes.get_ylim()
axes.axvline(7, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymin + 0.05*(ymax - ymin))
```

Note that I calculate the tick length automatically to be 5% of the axes height. This can of course be adjusted. Also, the `axvline` function takes more arguments to set e.g. the line width.